# Autocomplete не отключается

Tags: autocomplete, html

На странице отключено автозаполнение, но она все равно работает.
В чем может быть дело?

```
autocomplete=off
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autocomplete=off` это свойство используется [для не сохранения новых данных](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/autocomplete), а **не для отключения** автозаполнения (а если вы вводили ранее с настройками `autocomplete=on` - браузер запомнил и будет подставлять это значение).

А если у вас сохраняет новые данные с `autocomplete=off` и потом их же и выводит при автозаполнении, то я не знаю :)